# Simple cypher query on embedded graph DB from Java results in nullpointerexception

Tags: neo4j

Until now I have only interacted with neo4j through its browser and REST interface.
Now I want to interact with neo4j via Java and an embedded database.

I get a null pointer exception when I attempt to run a Cypher query. 
The console output did not help me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:58)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:54)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at neo.project1.App.main(App.java:59)
```

- My config

  - Ubuntu 14.04
  - neo4j/stable,now 2.0.2 all [installed]
  - java version "1.7.0_55"
  - **[Link to .java file and pom file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B3C5FAE4A9EDE98F!285)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
```

Sounds like your original constructor call (with the second parameter as NULL) is letting the ExecutionEngine try to use a NULL logger.

Comment: Thanks. That lead to a stack trace that was useful. It turns out the ExecutionResult.dumpToString must be inside of a transaction. It now works.